# logrotate an entire folder when total size exceeds a limit

Tags: ubuntu, logrotate

I have a bunch of logfiles under /var/log/foo/; I want to compress the whole folder if the
total size of the folder exceeds certain limit. Is it possible to do it without adding 
additional cron job.

Answer (score 0):

As per [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) of `logrotate`:

> logrotate is designed to ease administration of systems that generate
> large numbers of **log files**

And when talk about size in config file you will read this:

> size
>
> Log files are rotated only if they grow bigger then size bytes

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add cron job And you can't limit the size of your folder.

BUT, Logrotate is doing all the work you need. Logrotate script is running by default as a daily periodic (/etc/cron.daily/logrotate). You can add your own logrotate config file (/etc/logrotate.d/your_logrotate_config) which will include limits.

For instance (/etc/logrotate.d/foo):

```
/var/log/foo # logs path
{
    rotate 4      # limit number of files
    size 10M      # limit to 10 Mb
    weekly        # if less than size limit, it will rotate by expired time
    compress      # compressed file
    delaycompress
}
```

In case logrotate scrip runs every day, it will be implement if file's size is bigger than 10Mb. Max log files at the folder (/var/log/foo) is limited to 4, Otherwise it will remove old files.

Conclusion:

1. limit the logrotate size.
2. limit the sum of files.
3. deffine (used crontab) logrotate script to run in a Short cycles (for instance every hour).
4. compress your log filed.

Good Luck!